# Getting nth cell in row on button click

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to figure out how to get value of the nth cell in same row as button that was clicked in angular2. So far only understand that i have to pass the $event value but not sure how to extract the relevant data.

in app.component.html

```
<table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Identifier</th>
          <th>Check Identifier</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td hidden>1</td>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td><button (click)="getData($event)">Display</button></td>
          <td>View</td>
        </tr>        
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

in app.component.ts i have following function setup

```
getData(event: any) {
console.info(event);

// this bit not sure how to do
}
```

In the above scenario how would I extract the value 1 from the first cell in the row after clicking the Display button?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Usually the data comes from some model and it's usually better to access the model instead of reading from the DOM.

Comment: When you look at the output from `console.info(event);`, does it have what you expect in it, somehwhere? You can always just pass the value into the function if you need to.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer i might go down the path of model (still need to figure out that bit), in mean time i am trying to figure out this method.

Comment: @R.Richards nope, tried that path hence the console.info

Comment: How do you generated the n elements? Do you add them manually or using `*ngFor` or similar methods to generate them from data?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer currently manually for learning purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td hidden #nth>1</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td><button (click)="getData($event, nth)">Display</button></td>
      <td>View</td>
    </tr>        
  </tbody>
```

```
getData(event: any, el HTMLElement) {
  console.info(event);
  console.log(el.innerHTML);    
}
```